# How to set max-height of ImageView at runtime

Tags: android, android-imageview

**How do I set the max height of the ImageView at runtime?**

For example, i have a `image url` and that has the width greater then the screen width. Then i want to set the `ImageView height as screen's width`, to make ImageView as square.

I can't find the perfect solution for this. Any help will be appreciated deeply.

Comment: AFAICT, you will need to do it manually. That is, give hardcoded width/height to your `ImageView`

Comment: Make your imageview as 'invisible' and in onResume set your imageview's width and height then set it as 'visible'. You may need to use a separate thread to do it. Hope it will work.

Comment: @Mamta Kaundal when your application is started that time u get your devices width and set that in your image view other wise set that in your piccasso  library resize width & height

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't matter for the size of image, the code below will size with the perfect ratio, it will make max width without making resolution suck.if you dont want max width then modify the dimensions from code. You ll need picasso.

```
   private Dimensions getScreenDimensions()
{
    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager)    context.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
    display.getMetrics(metrics);
    final int widthScreen = metrics.widthPixels;
    int heightScreen = metrics.heightPixels;
    Dimensions screenDimen = new Dimensions(metrics.widthPixels,metrics.heightPixels); // custom class
    return screenDimen;
}

    private Bitmap makeCalc(Dimensions screenDimen, Dimensions imageDimen,Bitmap bmp)
{
    float widthRatio = screenDimen.getWidth() / imageDimen.getWidth();
    float scaledHeight = imageDimen.getHeight() * widthRatio;
    imageBmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, (int)screenDimen.getWidth(), (int) scaledHeight, true);

    //image.setImageBitmap(resized);
    return imageBmp;
}

public class Dimensions {
float width;
float height;

public Dimensions(float width, float height) {
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
}

public float getHeight() {
    return height;
}

public void setHeight(float height) {
    this.height = height;
}

public float getWidth() {
    return width;
}

public void setWidth(float width) {
    this.width = width;
}
   }

    Target target = new Target() {
        @Override
        public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
            int width = bitmap.getWidth(); // original width
            int height = bitmap.getHeight(); // original heigh
            Log.w(TAG, "onBitmapLoaded: " + width + " " + height);

            Bitmap newBmp = makeCalc(getScreenDimensions(),new Dimensions(width,height),bitmap);
            imageView.setImageBitmap(newBmp);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {
            Log.w(TAG, "onBitmapFailed: "+errorDrawable );
        }

        @Override
        public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {
            Log.w(TAG, "onPrepareLoad: " );
        }
    };

    Picasso.with(this).load(yourURL).into(target);
    imageView.setTag(target);
```

Answer (score 0):

To make a Square ImageView you can use the following custom class:

```
public class SquareImageView extends ImageView {

    public SquareImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public SquareImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public SquareImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        //noinspection SuspiciousNameCombination
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, widthMeasureSpec);
    }
}
```